# Accessing Function from a Nested Include in C++

Tags: c++, class

Trying to understand more complex project structure in C++. This is for an nrf52840 (embedded 2.4Ghz radio device). But the question is about C++ but using it for an example.

Say I have 5 files I created:

```
1) main.cpp
2) mouse.cpp
3) mouse.h
4) radio_controls.cpp
5) radio_controls.h
```

There is also a .h I included:

```
1) esb.h
```

In esb.h there is a function called esb_set_rf_channel(int) which is used to set a frequency on the radio device to receive and transmit on. I included it in radio_controls.h since I use functions defined in esb.h in the radio_controls.h and radio_controls.cpp.

I included radio_controls.h in mouse.cpp since I need to control the radio device for the mouse to mostly transmit move commands.

Is this even proper? What is the recommended standard? I now can call esb_set_channel(int) directly in mouse.cpp but the intent was to have all the radio stuff in radio_controls and maybe have a helper member function call it for me from radio_controls. I also want to avoid including header files too many times where you might start to run into issues since esb.h is not my file as a project gets larger I could see this as an issue.

Edit: Code for more clarity. Main problem is I need a structure from esb.h in radio_controls.h. Maybe I could have a struct of my own for the settings I want to change and have the implantation file create the esb.h struct on the stack? This seems terrible too.

radio_controls.h

```
#ifndef RADIO_CONTROLS_H
#define RADIO_CONTROLS_H

#include <esb.h>

class RadioControls {
private:
    esb_config config; // this structure is from esb.h (this is why I need the #include <esb.h> here

    // config changes from default that need to be added by mouse
    // and need to set RF 
    //config.retransmit_delay = 250; // lower retransmit delay from default of 600 
    //config.event_handler = event_handler; // add radio event handler

    int clocks_start(void); // start HF clock (needed for ESB to work)
    int esb_initialize(void); // initialize esb radio
    // want a structure for esb initialize values to be passed in

    // rx and tx payloads
    static struct esb_payload rx_payload;
    static struct esb_payload tx_payload;

public: 
    RadioControls(); // initialize radio on nrf device
    int esb_set_rf_channel(uint32_t channel); // set rf channel to first element in array of unifying
    // could be a helper function like set_rf(uint32 channel); and implementation file calls esb.h defined one

}; // namespace controls::radio

#endif // RADIO_CONTROLS_H



#ifndef MOUSE_H
#define MOUSE_H

/*
 * Initialize mouse.
 * 
 * And need to restore any settings from 
flash. 
 * 
 */
class mouse {
    private:
    // restore mouse settings from flash

public:
    Mouse(); // create unifying mouse
    // ~Mouse(); // reset to default and disable

    // int move_mouse(); // x, y mouse move command

    // initialize esb radio

    // set radio to default settings for mouse
    // this includes RF, address for pipes, etc. 
};

#endif // MOUSE_H
```

Comment: It would help if you would show your *actual* code instead of just *describing* the code.

Comment: I kept trying and the formatting kept messing up. Would leave out half the code.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Steve4879, yes, There's a way to use structures from the esb.h. You can use `forward declaration` for it. Take a look:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <memory>

class ClassFromLibrary;
struct StructFromLibrary;

namespace controls::radio {

std::shared_ptr<ClassFromLibrary> makeClassFromLib(const StructFromLibrary &data);

// here will be error:
ClassFromLibrary makeClassFromLib(StructFromLibrary data);
// Because the forward declared classes can only be pointers or referencies

} // namespace controls::radio
```

Comment: I was struggling to ask the question right but that is exactly what I was looking for. Probably why I had a hard time finding the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a little rule that helps me make my code a little bit clear. The rule sounds like that:

> Do not add include directives in header files

Sometimes it's impossible, and that's OK. In your solution, you can make your `radio_controls.h` as clear as possible. Something like that:

```cpp
#pragma once

namespace controls::radio {

using result_t = unsigned char;

result_t initialize();

result_t set_channel(const unsigned char channel);

} // namespace controls::radio
```

And your cpp file could be like:

```cpp
#include "radio_controls.h"
#include <esb.h>

namespace controls::radio {

result_t initialize() {
    return esb_init();
}

result_t set_channel(const unsigned char channel) {
    return etb_set_rf_channel(channel);
}

} // namespace controls::radio
```

I didn't use classes in my examples because, as I understand, you're an embedded developer, but I still highly recomend to use classes in a case like that. You could make a class named `radio::Controls` or etc.
But, of course, if your compiler allows doing it. Anyway, I hope I answered to your question.

Assuming I can make another rule:

> Include additional functionality only in those files, where you really need it.
> Avoid to add includes into header files

Comment: Great! I thought about doing that too just was not sure that was common or accepted to just have a function that calls another function for isolation reasons.

Edit: Actually there are some structures from esb.h I want to use in radio_controls.h. In that case is there still a best practice?